# How do I draw a field with a custom property drawer into my custom inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very lost. What I want to do is to draw the property drawer of the InputAction class:
[image]

In a custom editor for a class.

I believe that I would need to use EditorGUILayout.PropertyField() in order to achieve this. However, I would need to convert an instance of the class InputAction into a SerializedProperty in order to pass it through the function. I do not know how to convert this.

I am not too sure if I am on the right track; Property Drawers confuse me, and scanning through the input's system code confuses me even more.

So if I were to boil the question down to one, generalizable question, it would be:
**"How do I draw a field with a custom property drawer into my custom inspector?"**

Thank you! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) to draw a custom property inside a custom inspector. Here is a decent blog post describing [how to draw a field with a custom property drawer in a custom inspector](http://anthor.co.uk/blog/2015/12/06/unity-tip-custom-propertydrawer-inside-custom-inspector.html).

You are rightly confused on how to convert `InputAction` to `SerializedProperty` though, since you can't. [InputAction](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html) is a plain C# class, while a [SerializedProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) can only be constructed from a `UnityEngine.Object`. It's possible Unity is drawing that whole window using a custom editor, not piecewise using custom properties.

It's possible that you could extend the editor used to draw that window though, since the InputSystem package includes documentation on at least one custom editor: [InputParameterEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Editor.InputParameterEditor.html). I haven't looked into that much myself yet, good luck!